# Using OpenTextFile with a .tmp file

Tags: vbscript

I am using a software called Move It Central. It allows for the uploading of VBScripts to be used against various files. The line `MICacheFilename()` returns `C:\TEMP\path\file.tmp` however this file is a simple txt file.

I am attempting to count how many lines are in this text file with the `OpenTextFile` method however I get the error `Object doesn't support this property or method`. I can't seem to figure out why I am getting this. The script is below. I believe a lot of the problem is user error as I am incredibly new to VBS

```
Sub main()
    Dim objFSO, textInput, strTextFile, actualRows, testRows, mFunction, strTemp
    CONST ForReading = 1

    MISetTaskParam "cachedFile", mFile
    textInput = "the next line is the cachedFile"
    MILogMsg textInput
    MILogMsg mFile


    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strTextFile = MICacheFilename()
    textInput = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strTextFile,ForReading)
    testRows = MIGetTaskParam("testRows")

    Do While textInput.AtEndOfStream <> True
        strTemp = textInput.SkipLine
    Loop
    IF textInput.Line-1 >= testRows THEN
        MILogMsg "true"
    ELSE
        MILogMsg "false"
    END IF
end sub
main
```

Comment: what happens whjen you replace your  strTextFile with strTextFile = "C:\Temp\path\file.tmp" ? Does it work?  I'm wondering if MICacheFilename isn't returning a string.  Without seeing that function, it might be tough to tell.

Comment: I would attempt that but I believe that file is only in the temp folder when the task (move it central) executes. And the file name and whatnot is all randomly generated. Any idea on how I could get around that?

Comment: execute the function (but don't try to set it to a string).  So first, in your script, just call MICacheFileName(). I suspect that function creates the file and doesn't return a string like you're currently trying. If it is always in the temp folder, then you can do a search in that folder (after the function runs) for the .tmp file using FileExists, and then process it.

Answer (score 2):

you missed out the `SET` keyword

`set textInput = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strTextFile,ForReading)`

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278834.aspx